CSS properties doesn't work on IOS devices
I have added these but it's not working when we check in iOS. I have tried to align this in center, it's working fine on desktop, Android, but in iOS it's not working. I want it working on iOS as well.
I have checked every browser on iOS and it's not working there
#google_translate_element_mobile .goog-te-gadget .goog-te-combo {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    text-align-last: center;
}


I cannot comment on your question but there is a very helpful prewritten css file called normalize css which removes the system or browser differences.
At the end just link it to your main file. Hope this helps!
